# Is there an acceptable range for the values of MDs and SMDs? If MDs go below and beyond -1 and 1, respectively, are my results still valid?

Tags: r, interpretation, meta-analysis, standardized-mean-difference

I'm not certain whether my subgroup meta-analyses that produced extreme(?) values of MD (highest is 13.86 [95%-CI, 12.44; 15.29] and lowest at -15.42 [95%-CI, -20.63; -10.20]) are still valid. I used the random effects model for a highly heterogeneous data (790 pairwise observations).

Is there are an acceptable range for MDs to determine whether the results valid? Also, are resulting MDs from subgroup analyses comparable to an SMD that’s an outcome of the overall meta-analysis of the same dataset? I’m just really confused with the boundaries between these two measures.

Help?

Comment: SMD or MD? If SMD those are so enormous that I don't believe them. If MD, they are fine.

Comment: Sorry. Those values are MD. Anyway, thanks! But for the SMD, I got a value of -0.86 with 95%CI -0.98; -0.74.

Comment: Without more context it is hard to say but if you expected the intervention to have a large effect you have confirmed that.